Is there a built-in way to copy a file from current directory to previous directory?
My pwd is /long_path/lots/of/subs/waydeep/. If I cd -, it will return me to /lastdirectory/long_pathway/very_deep/.
Is there a shortcut terminal/cli command to copy file1.ex from the current working directory to the last working directory? (It might look like cp file1.ex -/.) If I moved files between these two frequently, I could create a soft link, but I want to find or make a more general solution.
If there is no built-in facility to do this, how could I add it -- let's say to my shell (bash)? I ask because the issue comes up often enough that it would be a useful thing to have ready.
Currently using linux Mint 23.1 and Fedora 40, but the question is general for most/any distribution, esp. using terminal (and possibly bash).

Use the builtin OLDPWD variable.
cd /path/to/first/location
cd /path/to/second/location
cp "some file" "$OLDPWD"

